# How can I load many csv files as tabs in Excel on MacOS

Tags: ms-office

I have a folder with about 140 CSV files.

I would like to create one spreadsheet with each CSV being one tab.

There seems to be straightforward methods to do this, but all the searches I did point to menu items that do not exist on MacOS.

For example this:

- https://blog.golayer.io/excel/combine-csv-files
- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/open-multiple-csv-as-multiple-sheets-in-single/6bfea460-2474-4fa7-bbbf-8b89874870ab
- https://www.masterdataanalysis.com/ms-excel/import-csv-files-folder-excel/

An additional question: Is there a known reason why Excel on Mac is so different from Windows? It even uses different keyboard shortcuts, but they're not native to the Mac either.

Comment: MS has always had a separate developer team specifically for Office Mac. Maybe they don't talk enough to the Windows team.

Comment: Interesting take on the myth that [Microsoft 'saved' Apple](https://www.zdnet.com/article/stop-the-lies-the-day-that-microsoft-saved-apple/) from folding.

Comment: @IconDaemon, I never heard that before; I had heard they had invested in it to prevent becoming a monopoly.

Comment: @Thomas any luck solving this? I have the same issue

Comment: @UthsavChitra, yes, I wrote a small tool using the EPPlus dotnet package and you can make multiple tabs in a file. But no command line solution, etc